# Do I need to free the returned pointer from localtime() function?

Tags: c, pointers, time, free

I am currently reading the manpages about `time.h`. I got this far:

```
time_t now = time(0);
struct tm * local = localtime(&now);
```

Now I can work with the time, as far as good, but I do not find the information if its my duty to `free()` the variable `local` or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quoting the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime)

> The four functions `asctime()`, `ctime()`, `gmtime()` **and `localtime()` return a pointer to static data** and hence are not thread-safe. [...]

So, you need not `free()` the returned pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Looked in implementation of localtime() in bionic lib c code
Some code from it. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/libc/tzcode/localtime.c

```
static struct tm    tm;

static struct tm *
localtime_tzset(time_t const *timep, struct tm *tmp, bool setname)
{
  int err = lock();
  if (err) {
    errno = err;
    return NULL;
  }
  if (setname || !lcl_is_set)
    tzset_unlocked();
  tmp = localsub(lclptr, timep, setname, tmp);
  unlock();
  return tmp;
}
struct tm *
localtime(const time_t *timep)
{
  return localtime_tzset(timep, &tm, true);
}
```

SO here it return address of static structure tm.

**So we do not need to free it.** And other function of that family also access that global static structure so its not thread safe.